# How to change controls list on excited videojs instance?

Tags: video.js

I need a play an advertising before a main video in videojs player, when i playing an advertsing i need have no controls in my video.
How to change controls list on excited **videojs** instance ?

Answer (score 1):

`videojs("video_id").controls(false)` will disable the controls (where "video_id" is the id of your video element).